# Insatall Apk_File Path unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, path, build.gradle, apk

I want to install the apk file, so according to what I understand, I must use the file provider, and when I use the file provider, it shows two errors.

This is  code of install :

```
try
{
   

    AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

    AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
    AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");
    AndroidJavaObject uriClass = new AndroidJavaObject("android.net.Uri");
    AndroidJavaObject fileProviderClass = new AndroidJavaClass("androidx.core.content.FileProvider");


    // Set the action to view
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_VIEW"));

    // Get the content URI using FileProvider
    AndroidJavaObject contentUri = fileProviderClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getUriForFile", currentActivity, "com.DefaultCompany.BallBattle.fileprovider", new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", apkPath));

    // Set the data and type to the content URI and MIME type for APK files
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setDataAndType", contentUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

    // Add flag to grant read permission to the content URI
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", intentClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION"));

    currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);

    Deb.text = "Success";
    

}
catch (AndroidJavaException ex)
{
    Deb.text = "error" + ex;
}
```

this is the mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
            <provider
           android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
           android:authorities="com.DefaultCompany.BallBattle.fileprovider"
           android:exported="false"
           android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
            </provider>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this the  path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

error

```
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34

This Android Gradle plugin (7.1.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=34
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 34

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

2-```Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:D:\hamza\My project\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\launcher\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:99: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

```
How do I fix the problem????


I changed a lot inside main gradle
```